# Añadir campos de búsqueda a una tabla de Jhipster

Tags: html, angular, html-tabla, jhipster

He creado mi aplicación utilizando jHipster. En las tablas, he conseguido añadir la paginación y la ordenación, pero también me gustaría añadir un campo de búsqueda en  una columna, algo como esto http://ng-table.com/ ¿Sabéis si hay algún atributo de estas tablas que permitan hacerlo, o alguna otra forma?

Mi HTML es este:

```
<div class="table-responsive" *ngIf="entities">

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr jhiSort [(predicate)]="predicate" [(ascending)]="reverse" [callback]="transition.bind(this)">
    <th jhiSortBy="id"><span jhiTranslate="global.field.id">ID</span> <span class="fa fa-sort"></span></th>
    <th jhiSortBy="nombre"><span jhiTranslate="app.entity.name">Name</span> <span class="fa fa-sort"></span></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let entity of entities ;trackBy: trackId">
        <td><a [routerLink]="['../entity', entity.id ]">{{entity.id}}</a></td>
        <td>{{entity.name}}</td>                               
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el atributo 'pureFilter' de angular, usando también una entrada de texto para el filtro, sería algo como esto:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filter" class="form-control">

<table> 
......
<tr *ngFor="let entity of (entities | pureFilter:filter:'name')>
.......
```

En 'pureFilter' tienes que poner 'pureFilter:[El Nombre del filtro]:[El atributo de la entidad sobre el que filtrar]'

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer los siguiente:

En el componente, puedes poner los siguiente:

```
loadAll(idUser) {
this.userService
  .getAllVoterParent({
    page: this.page - 1,
    size: this.itemsPerPage,
    sort: this.sort(),
    idCandidate: idUser,
    q: this.search !== undefined ? this.search : ''
  })
  .subscribe((res: HttpResponse<User[]>) => this.onSuccess(res.body, res.headers), (res: HttpResponse<any>) => this.onError(res.body));


 }
```

donde **q** es el criterio de busqueda.

En el servicio:

```
getAllVoterParent(req?: any): Observable<HttpResponse<IUser[]>> {
const options = createRequestOption(req);
options.set('idCandidate', req.idCandidate);
options.set('q', req.q);
return this.http.get<IUser[]>(`${this.resourceUrl}/get-all-voters`, { params: options, observe: 'response' });


 }
```

ya en el controller:

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/users/get-all-voters", params = {"idCandidate"})
@PreAuthorize("hasRole(\"" + AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN + "\") or hasRole(\"" + AuthoritiesConstants.CANDIDATO + "\")")
public ResponseEntity<List<UserDTO>> getAllVotersByCandidate(@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams,
                                                             UriComponentsBuilder uriBuilder,
                                                             Pageable pageable,
                                                             @RequestParam(value = "idCandidate") Long idCandidate,
                                                             @RequestParam(value = "q", defaultValue = "") String q) {

    log.debug("REST request to get all voters by candidate: {}", idCandidate);
    final Page<UserDTO> page = userService.getAllVoterByParent(idCandidate, q, pageable);
    HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(uriBuilder.queryParams(queryParams), page);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
```

por ultimo en el Repositorio:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT v FROM User c" +
    " INNER JOIN User l ON  c.id = l.parent" +
    " INNER JOIN User v ON l.id = v.parent WHERE c.id = :idCandidate " +
    " AND (LOWER(v.firstName) LIKE  concat('%',:q,'%') OR LOWER(v.lastName) LIKE concat('%',:q,'%')" +
    " OR v.numDocument LIKE  concat('%',:q,'%'))")
Page<User> getAllVotersByCandidate(@Param("idCandidate") Long idCandidate, @Param("q") String q, Pageable pageable);
```

**@Query** es un ejemplo, ahi puedes poner la consulta que se ajuste a tus necesidades